# Looping through the text file in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have read a local file `flight.txt`

```
1 DFW BOM 2016-05-20 12:20 2016-05-21 02:40 1084.00 JetAirways 100
2 DFW DEL 2016-04-24 17:15 2016-04-25 07:20 1234.00 Lufthansa 100
3 DFW FRA 2016-06-05 13:30 2016-06-05 03:32 674.00 AmericanAirlines 100
```

Code used to read a file in typescript.

```
 populateFlightList() {
   let data = fs.readFileSync('flight.txt').toString('utf-8'); {
        let textByLine = data.split("\n")
        console.log(textByLine);

    };
```

now i want to loop and read from the file and parse data into flight objects
by creating a new object in each iteration and adding it to an arraylist.

```
   try {
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(file);                
        while(fin.hasNext()) {
          int number = fin.nextInt();                 //flight numer
          String from = fin.next();                   //Departure airport
          String to = fin.next(); //Arrival airport
    }**Code in Java**
```

how do i do this in typescript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `readline` module to read one line at a time. Parsing the data will still be a manual affair:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as rd from 'readline'

var reader = rd.createInterface(fs.createReadStream("W:\\tmp\\stack\\2\\data.txt"))

var data: Array<{ number: number; from: string; to: string}> = [];
reader.on("line", (l: string) => {
    var tokens = l.split(' ');
    var nr= parseInt(tokens[0]);
    var from = tokens[1];
    var to = tokens[2]
    console.log(`nr: ${nr} from ${from} to ${to}`);
    data.push({
        number: nr, from, to
    });
})
console.log(`Will be empty data has not yet been read ${data.length}` );

reader.on("close", ()=> {
    console.log(`Data has been read ${data.length}` );
    data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(`nr: ${element.number} from ${element.from} to ${element.to}`)
    });
})
```

The `line` event will be triggered once for each line. The `close` event will trigger after the entire file has been read and the file closed, this is where the entire data set will be available, which we build up one entry at a time, each time the `line` event occurs.

For more about the readline module consult the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)

Comment: what does createInterface,createReadStream & reader.on("line", (l: string)  do?

Comment: You can consult the documentation for a more detailed explanation of the readline module  https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html. But the idea is that `createInterface` needs a readable stream (of a file in this case) which can be obtained from the `fs` module. The `on('line', ...` adds an event listener for when new lines are available, and the callback passed to it will be called for each line.

Comment: How do i store the above object in ArrayList like this  **static ArrayList<Flight> flightList= new ArrayList<>();**

Comment: Expanded the code to save the data in an array and write it out when all the data has been read into the array. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can we continue discussion in chat.. few more doubts.

Comment: Sure, I'm on chat, feel free to contact me